# JS function call not working within a jade file for onclick button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, function-call

I'm using express for a project. I'm using jade (pug) for my view engine and am rendering this page where I have 3 radio buttons:

```
html
  head
    script(src='../public/javascripts/player_id.js')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/index.css')
  body
    block content
    #checkboxes
      input(type='radio', name='platform', value='1', onclick="platformSelect(1);")
      input(type='radio', name='platform', value='2', onclick="platformSelect(2);")
      input(type='radio', name='platform', value='3', onclick="platformSelect(3);")
```

platfromSelect(value) is a function from 'player_id.js'  :

```
function platformSelect(value){
if (value==1) {
    platform = steam;
} else if (value==2) {
    platform = xboxone;
} else if (value==3) {
    platform = ps4;
}
console.log("Platform selected: ", platform);
```

}

The 'console.log' never gets called, so I'm assuming the function never gets called. I have tried syntactic changes to the onclick value call as follows:

```
onclick="platformSelect(1);"
onclick='platformSelect(1);"
onclick='platformSelect(1)'
```

but none seem to work. I appreciate the help.

Comment: put a console.log at the beginning of the function to be sure

Comment: what are the values of the variables: steam, xboxone, & ps4?

Comment: console.log at the beginning still shows nothing. Also that is my mistake, those should be strings: platform = "steam";

Comment: Have you verified the path to your js file is correct?

Comment: Yup. I'm now taking the approach to passing the function as a parameter when rendering the page, but I'm not having any luck with that either. Let me know if you guys want any extra information.